# Different count column in one query

Tags: postgresql-9.3

```
SELECT created_at::timestamp::date AS date, count(id) AS all FROM myTable
WHERE created_at > current_date - interval '130' day
GROUP BY created_at::timestamp::date
```

As result I get 2 columns.
**Date** and total count of rows (**all**).

Nice.

But I also need to add third column that show count of rows by some filter.
Here another sql query:

```
select count(id) from myTable
where data->'payment'->>'type' = 'card-online'
```

Column **data**  has type jsonb.

Nice.

But I need to replace this 2 sql queries by ONE SQL query.
As result must be 3 columns: **date**, **all**, **online_count**

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. You can use **FILTER**

E.g.

```
SELECT created_at::timestamp::date AS date,
COUNT(1) AS all,
COUNT(1) FILTER (WHERE data->'payment'->>'type' = 'card-online') AS online_count
FROM MyTable 
WHERE created_at > current_date - interval '130' day
GROUP BY created_at::timestamp::date
ORDER BY created_at::timestamp::date DESC
```